# how to navigate among the buttons with the arrow keys

Tags: c#

I have some buttons which is created dynamically in my winform , on which the first button should be selected by default and the rest of the buttons should be selected clicking the down and up arrows.

```
 for (int i = 0; (i < 5); i++)
        {

           Button btn = new Button();


            btn.Width *= 2;
            btn.Height *= 2;


            yPos = yPos + btn.Height + space;

            Point p = new Point();
            p.X = xPos;
            p.Y = yPos;
            btn.Location = p;

            this.Controls.Add(btn);
        }
```

the buttons is displayed in a row style and clicking on down arrow should select  the next immediate button and like that. 
Please help me what can i write in the keypress event

Comment: on the form its self you need to wire up a key press event and then look for the specific keys. If this question doesn't get closed ill give you an example in an answer shortly

Comment: public override void DownNavigation_Click(EventArgs e)
        {
            index += 5;

            if (index <= entries.Count)
            {

                ShowList(entries);
            }

            else
            {

                index = entries.Count;


             
                return;


            }

            return;

          
        } DownNavigation represents down arrow key. This code display the next 5 buttons , ie  from 5 to 10 .  5 buttons will be displayed at a time.   I want to select the immediate next button with the down arrow key

Comment: if the answer isn't what youre looking for, be more clear in your question

Answer (score 1):

Add your `Button` to a `List<Button> BtnList`, define a index `int current = 0`.
When keypress

```
if(current == BtnList.Length)
{
    current = 0;
}
else
{
    BtnList[current].Focus();
    current += 1;
}
```

Comment: remeber add this in `if(e.KeyCode == Keys.??)`

Comment: Thanx .. I have used this logic , with some modifications and it is working. Thank you so much ..

Comment: you're welcome, if you don't mind mark this as answer.